# Why is this method not returning nil when a and b are equal?

Tags: ruby, conditional-operator

This method should return the sum of all numbers between `a` and `b` (not ordered) and should return `a` or `b` if they are equal.

```
def get_sum(a,b)
  a < b ? (a..b).sum : (b..a).sum
end
```

I'm curious as to why this method doesn't return nil when `a` and `b` are equal. The ternary operator takes care of the condition where `a` is less than or greater than `b` so I'm tempted to add `return a if a==b` before the ternary to test if they are equal but it appears it's not necessary.

For example, if `a=5` and `b=5` then the value returned is `5`. Could someone explain why this is please?

Comment: The "else" part is not equivalent to `a > b` but to `!(a < b)` which includes `a == b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how the `<` operator (or rather method) works.

`a < b`

It returns `true` if `a` is less than `b`, otherwise it returns `false`.

Therefore `5 < 5` returns `false`.

By writing `a..b` you create a `Range` object `Range.new(a, b)`, which starts at `a` and goes up to and including `b`. Afterwards you call the `sum` method on this object.

Since the range `5..5` goes from `5` to and including `5`, when you convert it to an array you get:

```rb
(5..5).to_a #=> [5]
```

And the `sum` method adds all numbers which are within this range. And since this range includes a single number `5`, the result of this operation is `5`.

```rb
(5..5).sum #=> 5
```

Your method could be written more concisely

```rb
def get_sum(a, b)
  (a < b ? a..b : b..a).sum
end
```

To make it return `0` when `a` and `b` are the same, you could use an *exclusive* range with three dots `...`.

```rb
def get_sum(a, b)
  (a < b ? a...b : b...a).sum
end

get_sum(5, 5) #=> 0
get_sum(5, 6) #=> 5
get_sum(5, 7) #=> 11
```

Comment: *To make it return 0 when a and b are the same, you could use a exclusive range with three dots ...* - may be it's better `return 0` on condition? Because `get_sum(5, 6) #=> 5` looks strange :)

Comment: The whole idea behind this method is logically flawed in my opinion. This way it would be inconsistent

`get_sum(5, 5) #=> 0` `get_sum(5, 6) #=> 11`.

It would be sometimes acting like an exclusive range and other times like an inclusive one.

Answer (score 1):

the ternary operator has only two branches. if the condition is not truthy the latter is executed. there are no cases where no branches are executed (unless some error happens but that's another case).

you get nil only if you have only a branch and that's not executed. e.g.

```
def get_sum(a,b)
  if a < b  
    (a..b).sum
  end
end
```

for `get_sum(5, 5)` this evaluates to `nil`

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is no `Range#sum` because it is inherited from `Enumerable#sum`

So `(5..5).sum` it is the same as `(5..5).to_a.sum`

```
(5..5).to_a # => [5]
```

That's the reason

To fix it you can do something like this (change `else` branch of your ternary operator to `elsif`)

```
def get_sum(a, b)
  if a < b
    (a..b).sum
  elsif a > b
    (b..a).sum
  end
end

get_sum(1, 2) # => 3
get_sum(2, 1) # => 3
get_sum(5, 5) # => nil
```

But in my opinion `get_sum(5, 5) == 5` is more clear than `nil`

Comment: _"(5..5).sum it is the same as (5..5).to_a.sum"_ – result-wise yes, but the former is optimized for integer ranges. (which is odd because it would make much more sense to have an optimized `Range#sum` instead of a type check in `Enumerable#sum`)